# Does Spring-MVC annotation based bean validation support for collection-based property ? (Spring-MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I have a command class named Parent as follows:

```
public class Parent {

    private List<Child> childList;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And a Child class according to

```
public class Child {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private Integer age;

}
```

In [Spring validation module](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/docs/reference/0.8/html_single/#validation), i have been notice a @Cascade annotation.

Question: Does it work in collection-based property as in childList property ? If so, how can i use it ?

regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Hibernate Validator 4.0.0 Beta2, you can.

It based on JSR-303 Bean Validation.

Annotate Your List with @Valid to validate the content of the List

```
@Valid
private List<Child> childList;
```

Now validate:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Parent>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(Parent);
```

Comment: Does Spring-MVC support for it ?

Comment: You can do:

for(ConstraintViolation<Parent> constraint : validator().validate(parent)) {        
 bindingResult.rejectValue(constraint.getPropertyPath(), null, constraint.getMessage());            
}